# SlimDX: Error while loading Effect

Tags: c#, slimdx, effect

Im trying to load a effect in SlimDX, but I get a error when I try to get the ShaderSignature.
The error-code:

```
E_FAIL: An undetermined error occurred (-2147467259)
```

This is my code:

```
   EffectTechnique tech = this.effects.GetTechniqueByIndex(0);
   EffectPass pass = tech.GetPassByIndex(0);
   ShaderSignature shaderSignature = pass.Description.Signature;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can mean:

1. You forgot to install the [DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh452744.aspx).
2. You need to [try reinstalling](https://code.google.com/p/slimdx/issues/detail?id=370) the DirectX SDK.
3. Depending on your other code, you need to install the Debug Runtimes (specifically if you're using `CreateWithSwapChain` from one of the demos). This could also help get you more information.
4. You'll need to debug more. There's a page of [Debugging tips](http://slimdx.org/docs/#Debugging_Tips) you can use to try and track down the real issue.

Comment: But maybe Josh or Mike will show up and save the day.

Comment: Debug runtimes with all the spew they generate are *awesome* for, you know, debugging =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error was caused by the effect, i dont know exactly what was wrong, but I re-wrote it and know it works :) but thank you for the debugging tips.